# Wait for user id when using firestore collections

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to understand `rxJs` and I have been trying to use `where` query in Firestore collection but the output of this collection depends on getting the user ID from the Firebase Auth. So far this is what I have:

```
  userId: string;

  constructor(private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
              private auth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.auth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userId = user.uid;
      }
    });
    
    this.angularFirestore.collection('collection', k => k.where('user_id', '==', self.userId))
      .valueChanges({idField: 'id'}).subscribe(a => console.log(a), error => console.error(error.code, error.message));

  }
```

I am able to get the `userId`, but by the time it comes to the collection `userId` doesn't get passed on. Is there any way I can get the `userId` first and then the collection? One way is to move the collection into the `authState` subscription, but then I would have to do that whenever I have to call a collection. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the query **inside** the auth state subscriber callback so that it executes only after that user object is available.

Comment: That means I would have to do that every time I call a collection?

Comment: No, only you only need to do it iif you aren't certain that you have a signed in user currently. When a page loads for the first time, you have to wait for the subscriber before doing anything else that depends on that user.

Comment: The comment above fixes the issue. In my comment i hope to explain why the problem is happening. This.auth function is Async and returns an observable immediately. But the actual value will come later on from the server. However since it returns an observable then the next function down the line will run and it will try to use an id that didnt come yet. And thats why thr comment above told you to put the 2nd fn inside the first. So it runs only after the user is available

Comment: Ya, this is what I want to do in the first place. I thought there was a better way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Emitting `valueChanges` have to start after `this.userId` is set.

- `user$` -> sets `this.userId = user.uid` when authState emits value
- `valueChanges$` -> subscription to `collection` query by `this.userId` valueChanges
- `collection$` -> Starts emitting `valueChanges` once `userId` is set

```
ngOnInit() {
  const user$ = this.auth.authState.pipe(
    filter(user => !!user),
    tap(user => {
      this.userId = user.uid;
    })
  );

  const valueChanges$ = this.angularFirestore
    .collection("collection", k => k.where("user_id", "==", this.userId))
    .valueChanges({ idField: "id" });

  const collection$ = user$.pipe(
    take(1),
    mergeMap(_ => valueChanges$)
  );

  user$.subscribe();
  collection$.subscribe(
    a => console.log(a),
    error => console.error(error.code, error.message)
  );
}
```

Don't forget to `unsubscribe` your subscriptions.